# Supporting document for Tukish E-Visa

Tags: visas, paperwork, turkey, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistan national and will be travelling to Egypt (tourist visa) from Russia(Fan-ID) and am planning to stay for 2 to 3 days in Turkey. The E-visa site shows that I need a supporting document that is; visa or residence permit of USA, Schengen, UK or Ireland. But since I do not intend to travel to any of these countries what can I do?[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a Schengen/British/Irish/American visa or residence Permit, **you cannot enter Turkey on an e-visa** (you can get the e-visa by ticking the boxes and paying, but it will be invalid)

In that case, you need a transit visa from the Turkish embassy.